# how to handle exception for @secured in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I am using @secured in my spring boot application for a security reason. It gives me exception when i tried to access it with different roles.I can understand this. But how can I give a proper response to my front end instead of interal server error.This is my controller

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, Object> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.debug("in admin save user controller");
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(
                configProp.getProperty("moderator.created"), HttpStatus.OK,
                true, null);
    }
```

This is my exception is coming. Please help I am new in it.

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the *@Secured* annotation at service method level and then catch it inside controller returning your proper response.

Something like that:

**UserService.java**

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
public void saveUser(User user) {
   userRepository.save(user);
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    log.debug("in admin save user controller");

    try {
       userService.saveUser(user);
       return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(
            configProp.getProperty("moderator.created"), HttpStatus.OK,
            true, null);
    } catch(AccessDeniedException e) {
       log.warn("Unauthorized", e);
       return new ResponseEntity<Object>(configProp.getProperty("error.forbidden"), 
            HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the exception it is  clearly shows that the accessing USER doesn't have the proper role mapped to access the APIs, the accessing user role should be ROLE_ADMIN.

Comment: Pleas check his question?... he asks "But how can I give a proper response to my front end instead of interal server error?"